# Help with deleting items in a list, using PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of email addresses in a table, which is populated via an SQL query. Next to each email address, I've placed a submit button which I want to use to delete the email address that appears in that particular table row.

I thought of appending the email address to the name of each delete button, with the hope that it will take me in the right direction.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['email_adress']."</td><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\" name=\"delete".$row['email_adress']."\"></td></tr>";
```

I'm wondering how to use the delete button for each entry. Any help?

Comment: make it `name="delete[1]"`. And I'd rather use a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a button is absolutely a must, you could output a small form for each button and add a hidden field containing the id (or email, if you insist).  The form would submit the id or address in the hidden field, which you pick up in your processing script and run your delete query.

*edited to remove a portion of the answer that was determined to be an unwise method*

Comment: NEVER use links to alter your data.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Would you prefer the hidden form field way? That seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Yikes, didn't expect that response!  I just gave a quick solution without a lot of thought to the security implications.  Sorry, Jon, didn't mean to lead you astray.

Comment: @Jon Doesn't matter. Any field type as long as you're using POST method. However I see no use for the hidden field here. I'd rather use single form with checkboxes. But if you want separate forms, hidden would be okay.

Comment: As I wrote in another comment I think it's not such a big deal. However, I agree that everything that alters data should be POST and everything that specifies which data is to be retrieved should be GET.

Comment: @Vincent another lame comment. I'm glad that w3c guys don't share your opinion.

Comment: It's not an opinion, it's a fact. It isn't harder to modify POST headers than GET. It may not be as obvious, but it doesn't make your website more secure. Also, if you disagree with me, you don't have to be rude.

Comment: @Vincent: I think POST is safer than GET. If I had a link ?add_credit=10 and the web application user hits F5, the entity in question gets 20 credit. With POST the browser would have asked. And yes, Col. Shrapnel doesn't have to be rude. :)

Comment: Chrome browser also asks for confirmation. In both case, you re-submit the form. 
If you don't want your script to act like this, you have to code it.

Comment: @Vincent I disagree with overall level of SO answers/comments. It's just terrible. Every lame/unexperienced newbie eager to share their 5 cents. This site become greatest bloatware repository. That's what I disagree with. You can educate yourself by reading HTTP RFC and see what method should be used in what case.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with anything. I'm not sure you realise your comments are even more useless than mines. Obviously I'm not always right, nobody is, but if you don't bring any arguments or facts to the table, I don't understand why you expect me to believe you. You just look like another angry and arrogant user, I've seen plenty and trust me, I don't want to argue with one again. If you want to raise the general level on SO, you'd better start by teaching others now, otherwise stop complaining. You aren't helping more.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: Could you please edit your answer to remove the inaccuracies(mention that you did so) so that I can mark this as the answer?

Comment: @Jon: Wow, it's been a while.  Since there were objections to the idea of a link (probably justified), Shall I leave the portion of my answer at the end discussing form submission?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: Yes, you can leave the form submission part.

Comment: @Jon: Edits and note are complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are attempting to use submit buttons to contain data when submit buttons are not meant to contain data. Well they can and people do use them that way, but I prefer to use submit buttons to determine how to handle the data rather than to be the data in the submit.  There are two basic methods that I think would be a fair extension to what you are trying to do.

1.) Use links to issue the delete
2.) Use the submit button to issue the delete, but include a hidden form field to contain the email address to delete.

In the case of using a link you don't have to deal with a form, but I don't know about the rest of the page. If you are sending any other data, then a form is the ideal way. If you are just sending a single piece of data to delete the email, then I suggest a link. My recommendation come from a functional perspective. You might have a UI reason to a button that I don't know about.

In the case of using a form, the hidden field should contain the primary key (untested):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
           <td>".$row['email_adress']."</td>
           <td><form action="some/uri/to/something">
              <input type=\"hidden\" 
                 name=\"emailAddress\" value=\"{$row['email_adress']}\"/>
              <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\"
                name=\"delete".{$row['email_adress']}."\">";
              </form>
            </tr>
          </td>";
        }
```

You have to create a form around each submit else every hidden field in the form would be submitted telling you nothing about which email to delete. You can do many more things with the submit by using Javascript, but the simple method would be to just use a link -- forget about forms.

Answer (score 0):

so I've been messing around with this code trying to get a "prefetch browser add-on" to trigger something and kill my database... but I havn't been able to trigger anything yet... but I'd sure like to.

```
<?php
//CREATE AND POPULATE DB
if(!file_exists('a.sqlite')){
    $db = new SQLite3('a.sqlite');
    $db -> exec("CREATE TABLE test (idx INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, number INTEGER NOT NULL);");
    for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    $db -> exec("INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES (".(rand(1000,9999)).");");
    }
}else{
    $db = new SQLite3('a.sqlite');
}
//PERFORM DELETE FROM HREF
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete'])){
    $db -> exec("DELETE FROM test WHERE idx = ".$_REQUEST['delete'].";");
}

//SHOW CONTENTS OF BASE OR DELETE DB FILE
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test');
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    echo "<a href='test.php?delete=".$row['idx']."'>".$row['number']."</a></br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could do it like this but that would require to either execute the query again on the form's target page and then check for every combination of "delete".$row['email_adress'] or use a construction like this:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $dummy)
    if (substr($key,0,6) == 'delete')
        delete_entry(substr($key,6));
```

However, if you simply swap value and name...

```
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"".$row['email_adress']."\">
```

...you can just check $_REQUEST['Delete'] to find out which address button has been clicked.

Answer (score -1):

... I'm still not sure about displaying peoples emails on web pages unless it's company internal.. I gather we are in a secure company back office?
I'd go for the:

```
<a href=my_page.php?delete_email_id=456>email</a>
```

probably with some annoying javascript for the confirm

```
<a href=my_page.php?delete_email_id=456 onClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this email address ?')">email</a>
```

and catch it with a

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete_email_id']){ SQL UPDATE ENTRY...}
```

at the top of my_page.php

Comment: NEVER use JS confirmation that returns TRUE by default. Bots do not run JS

Comment: I can't see why not... I mean you can secure your pages in other ways.

Comment: You can't secure your page from your own browser. Google desktop search, various prefetches, etc.

Comment: I'm going to run some tests... I don't use any of the fore mentioned but I suppose that a pre-fetch thing that deletes all your data would be messy. How about Ajax-ing the href? I guess that would secure it.

Comment: I don't think such a prefetch exists. It would render every single web application (and the browser history) useless. Never heard of a "my browser clicked all the links" problem.

Comment: @AndreKR it's just matter of experience. Eventually you will.